# Mid-2017 13" Touch Bar Macbook Pro Won't Turn On or Charge

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, battery, charging

I am trying to diagnose a 13" mid-2017 touch bar MacBook Pro (Model A1706 EMC 3163) that will not charge or turn on.

This issue showed up a few days ago when the Apple-provided charger appeared to fail. The charger was replaced, and the computer and new charger worked fine for a day. After a day, it appeared to stop working. The battery went from 100% to 0% in a few hours while the computer was unplugged and asleep. Since then, it has been unable to charge or turn on. When the power button (touch ID button) is pressed, it displays the "plug in to charge" symbol. I have tried: SMC reset, using all four ports to charge, nvram reset (doesn't happen) and holding down a variety of startup key combinations (network recovery, diagnostics, etc).

My theory is that this is a hardware problem, either with the SMC chip or the power supply.

**Question: Are there any more software fixes I should try before taking this MBP in to an Apple store?**

Comment: Hmm, it does sound almost certainly to be a hardware issue. Did running Diagnostics reveal anything? I assume you've also tried using a different AC power source?

Comment: @Monomeeth It won’t boot into diagnostics. Yes, I tried a different AC source

Comment: Well, it seems to me your hands are tied. :( If you can't get it to power up then you can't explore the option of a software fix anyway. If you had enough juice in it I'd suggest trying to boot into Safe Mode to test for the extremely unlikely possibility that a kext or something was causing the problem, but I think a trip to the Apple Store is warranted. :(